# Extracting a Parse object of type Bool in xcode7 with swift 2 and using it's value in an if/else statement and get an error

Tags: parse-platform, boolean, swift2, xcode7

I'm trying to get this Parse object (Boolean) and using it in an if/else statement, but i get an error(on the line with "let basketballOn" line) when i call the object:

Cannot subscript a value of type '[PFObject]?' with an index of type 'String'

var BasketballB = PFObject()

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        let query = PFQuery(className: "Sports")
        query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (basketballB:[PFObject]?, error:NSError?) -> Void in
            if error == nil {
              let basketballON = basketballB["basketballBool"] as Bool

            } else {
                print(error)
            }


        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The query clearly returns an array of `PFObject`. This means you need to select which object from the array you want before checking the value of any key. To select the first object and test the value of its boolean key you should do something like this:

```
if let object = basketballB[0] {
    let basketballON = object["basketballBool"] as Bool
}
```